# Angularfire2 How to use AngularFireList to retrieve one item

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, angularfire2

In my angular application which use angularfire2 I have service where I fetch and store collection of orders. I store them in AngularFireList and fetch them using:

```
db.list('items').valueChanges();
```

However, in my component I need to get orders together with customer data from another location, I already managed to do it, but I use another Observable variable in my service to store joined data - is it desired design to have two collections in service which stores in part the same data (pure orders data seems dublicated to me)?

Second question, how to fetch only one order from collection of orders(of type AngularFireList) in my service? I dont want to make another request because I already have all data fetched in service, but when I try to make:

```
valueChange().pipe(filter(order => { order.id == desiredId };), first())
```

I receive observable, which resolves as array only with values, there is no keys. 
How to manage it?

If there is some design pattern to resolve such situation I would like to know them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) - yes, it's by design, you have streams (Observables) and you can combine them as you need to get desired behavior, the goal is to combine them correctly to avoid unexpected behavior.

For example when a service triggers backend on subscription and you don't want that you can add `shareReplay(1)` to return the latest know value instead of a real request.

2) you need to change your code a bit.

```js
sharedValueChange$ = valueChange().pipe(
  shareReplay(1),
);

// now these 2 will trigger only one valueChange() and share its emits.

allOrderChanges$ = sharedValueChange$.pipe(
  // some logic without a filter
);

desiredOrderChanges$ = sharedValueChange$.pipe(
  filter(order => order.id === desiredId),
  // first(), // if you don't want to receive its updates anymore.
);

desiredOrderChanges$.subscribe(); // doesn't trigger an extra time valueChange() 
desiredOrderChanges$.subscribe(); // doesn't trigger an extra time valueChange() 
desiredOrderChanges$.subscribe(); // doesn't trigger an extra time valueChange()
```

3) to debug resolve please add `tap(console.log)` right after the `filter` and put output into your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! ShareReplay did the thing here :) After debugging with tap I was able to resolve third point, hence no further help is needed.